# How to convert guest checkout order to My Account Order

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, guest-checkout

I have placed an `order` from guest account and the end of order I have given an option to create an `Account`, when I created the account and navigate to order sections i see no others.
So i expplored a bit but still i am not able to understand.

Right now my code loads the order information via this code

```
   public function getOrderInformation($orderid)
   {
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface')->load($orderid);
     return $order;
   }


    $shippingAddressObj = $orderInfo->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddressArray = $shippingAddressObj->getData();
    $paymentObj = $orderInfo->getPayment();
    $paymentArray = $paymentObj->getData();
```

also for order related information like name, quantity, size I use this

```
    <?php foreach ($orderInfo->getAllVisibleItems() as $item): ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can I achieve the same for guest user order, as I will be using the same `phtml` for my account(`guest` or `registered user`).

Answer (score 0):

You have used a data model class `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface` for you does not getting the data. You have to use  **Order repository interface `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface`or order repository** `Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository` for getting an order data.

If you have order Id then using  `Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository:get($id)` method, you will get orde details which you want event if place as register customer or guest customer.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface')->get($orderid);

$shippingAddressObj = $order->getShippingAddress();
$shippingAddressArray = $order->getData();
$paymentObj = $order->getPayment();
$paymentArray = $order->getData();
```

### Get Guest Customer Orders

```
<?php


namespace {namespace};

use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder;

class {Class}     {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var SortOrderBuilder
     */
    private $sortOrderBuilder;

    /**
     * @var FilterBuilder
     */
    private $filterBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder  $searchCriteriaBuilder,   
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder      
    ) {


        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->sortOrderBuilder = $sortOrderBuilder;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    public function getGuestOrders()
    {
        $customerEmail  = 'john@gmail.com';
        $filter1 = $this->filterBuilder->create()->setField('customer_email')
                ->setConditionType('eq')->setValue($customerEmail);
        $filter2 = $this->filterBuilder->create()->setField('customer_is_guest')
                ->setConditionType('eq')->setValue(1);
        $searchCriteria =$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters([$filter1,$filter2])
                ->create();
       $result = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
       if($result->getTotalCount() >0)
       {
           $orders = $result->getItems();
           foreach($orders as $order)
           {
                $guestCustomer = $order->getCustomerIsGuest();
                $groupId  = $order->getCustomerGroupId();
                $firstname = $order->getCustomerFirstname();
                $lastname = $order->getCustomerMiddlename();
                $lastname = $order->getCustomerLastname();
                $prefix = $order->getCustomerPrefix();
                $suffix = $order->getCustomerSuffix();
                $dob = $order->getCustomerDob();
                $taxvat = $order->getCustomerTaxvat();
                $gender = $order->getCustomerGender();
                $orderItems = $order->getItems();


           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i get order id for guest user order

Comment: So I have to write a different function to get orders for guest checkout orders? Even though after placing an order he creates his/her account. Then to display all orders in my account page, i used your code OrderRepositoryInterface. This will give me orders of guest too after placing order ?